# No carga la imagen al momento, tarda un rato aveces

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

No me cargan algunas imágenes y otras si. Al rato si dejas la app abierta, las que no se han abierto se abren, pero tardan un poco.

El error que salta es el siguiente:

```
======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following HttpException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Connection closed before full header was received, uri = https://urlejemplo/imagen.jpg

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
Image provider: NetworkImage("https://urlejemplo/imagen.jpg", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("https://urlejemplo/imagen.jpg", scale: 1.0)
====================================================================================================
```

Comment: Añade el código relativo a dónde estés usando la imagen, por favor. El error en sí mismo, no parece aportar mucha información.

Comment: ES importante agregues el código de lo que ratas de realizar

Answer (score -1):

Te aconsejo que uses [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) para que la imagen que consulta de la url se almacene en el directorio de caché, de igual manera podrás mostrar un indicador mientras el usuario espera que cargue la imagen, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
CachedNetworkImage(
     fit: BoxFit.fill,
     imageUrl: url,
     placeholder:(context, url) {
        return const SizedBox(
             width: 30,
             height: 30,
             child: Center(
             child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            );
          },
       )
```